# paypal website standard for subscription, cancelling subscription

Tags: paypal, subscription

Please help me with my requirement to implement using paypal.

My requirement is this :

The user can subscribe to a service, using paypal account or credit card ( without paypal account ) . The user can unsubscribe later if he/she wishes to .

I implemented the first part using Subscription button of "website standard" where paypal gave me a button and upon clicking it will lead to paypal website.

I am getting the notifications using IPN

Now there are two problems:

1. How to test credit card, I could test paypal account payment using the sandbox test users, but for the credit card, I dont have dummy credit cards. If I use the credit cards of the paypal accounts, it says "paypal users should use paypal to pay "
2. I want to cancel the subscription. The paypal user can go to the paypal account and cancel the subscription. That works fine. But how can we cancel the subscription from my website, or how can we cancel the subscription of the creditcard payer. The paypal SDK says the subscription profile ID is invalid.

Did anyone tried this kind of implementation. 
Any help would do, be it links or places to search .

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

First, Guest Checkout (paying with a credit card without signing into PayPal) is only available without recurring payments.  When using recurring payments it will force the person to create a PayPal account.  You would need to use Payments Pro in order to do recurring payments directly with credit cards, and then the person would never even be redirected over to PayPal at all.

For test cards, any old expired card you have would work, or what you can do is login to your PayPal sandbox account, go into the profile, and go through the process to add a new credit card to the account.  It will actually fill in a card number for you, but DO NOT add this card to the account.  Just copy that card number and then cancel out of this screen.  Now you can use that card number for testing on the PayPal system.

In order to refund using the API you'll need to create the profiles using the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API.  The profile ID that gives you will be compatible with all API calls to manage it in the future.